# How to read data from return jsonData in OneSignal Push Notification with Cordova

Tags: cordova, onesignal

I have been success sending data to server via PHP and get notificataion in android device.

PHP code :

```
function sendMessage(){
    $content = array(
        "en" => 'English Message'
        );

    $fields = array(
        'app_id' => "5eb5a37e-b458-11e3-ac11-000c2940e62c",
        'included_segments' => array('All'),
        'data' => array("foo" => "bar"), ---> I want to access this
        'contents' => $content
    );
```

Cordova Android handle notification receive :

```
window.plugins.OneSignal
.startInit("xxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxx")
.handleNotificationReceived(function(jsonData) {
 alert("Notification received:\n" + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
 // alert(jsonData.payload.additionalData.foo) -> error
})
.endInit();
```

From jsonData i want to access `array("foo" => "bar")`. in another thread using `jsonData.payload.additionalData`, also get an eror. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

After 2.0.9 version, you can get access to data using:

```
jsonData.notification.payload.additionalData.type
```

or

```
jsonData.notification.payload.additionalData.id
```

or

```
jsonData.notification.payload.additionalData.file
```